# SWT Communicate between Child shell and parent shell takes time

Tags: java, swt

We are using  a OTB Application called Teamcenter. I am writing a add on application that is invoked from a menu selection in the Teamcenter Application.

When they click the menu item, that executes a handler class and that creates the base dialog for my application.
It will Show Selected Component from Teamcenter on Open dialog .
Dialog has One text field with Button.
User go back to parent window and select item and then click button on dialog this will set selected item on opened dialog.

But When Dialog open and i go back to parent i.e OTB teamcenter application for selecting item it takes time it looks like it got hanged.

### Note:

### Text           Button

### List

text and button are adjacent field.

If user select 1200 parts and goto menu and select item then it will show popup and then click on parent window for single item selection,clicking on parent takes time 
but if we have 200 parts and then go back and click on parent window it doesn't take much time

Can anyone please suggest how to improve time performance ?

// open( ) : First Call on Menu selection  will call open() method
//setSourceBomLinesOnSessionInfo() :Call from Open method() to set Required selected item information in session required to be set on Dialog List component
// SetScope() :Set text data on button selection on opened dialog 
// user will go on parent window and select item and then coming back on opened dialog and click button

```
public void open()
    {
        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.debug("open 'OTM Compare' Dialog");
        eQOTMSessionInfo.getInstance().clearCurrentSelection();
        Shell prevShell = getOTMCompareDialog();
        if (prevShell != null)
        {
            prevShell.setMinimized(false);
        }else{
            try{        
                //Set Source BomLine on OTM Dialog Window 

                bSetInputOnDialog = setSourceBomLinesOnSessionInfo();
                if( bSetInputOnDialog )
                {
                    initializeUIComponents();
                    mainDialogShell.open();
                    Display display = mainDialogShell.getDisplay();
                    while (!mainDialogShell.isDisposed()) {
                        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                            display.sleep();
                        }
                    }
                    mainDialogShell.dispose();
                }
                else if (mainDialogShell != null)
                {
                    mainDialogShell.dispose();
                }

                eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:Exit initialize UI Components for OTM compare dialog.");
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("Exception occurred while initializing UI Components for OTM compare dialog. Error: "+th.getMessage(),th);
            }

        }
    }



//Initialize UI Component

    private void initializeUIComponents() throws TCException
    {
        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:In initialize UI Components for OTM compare dialog !!!");

        mainDialogShell = new Shell(this.m_parentShell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM |SWT.MODELESS);
        mainDialogShell.setText(this.m_sOTMDialogTitle);
        mainDialogShell.setLocation(getParent().toDisplay(300, 200));
        mainDialogShell.setSize(450, 400);

    /*  Image dialogicon = new Image(mainDialogShell.getDisplay(),"icon/ecubeIcon.png");

        mainDialogShell.setImage(dialogicon);
    */  

        /*Main grid*/
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(4, false);
        gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;
        mainDialogShell.setLayout(gridLayout);

        //Scope label to display on UI
        new Label(mainDialogShell, SWT.NONE|SWT.CENTER).setText("Scope:");

        //Text filed for scope
        this.m_textScopeName = new Text(mainDialogShell,SWT.READ_ONLY|SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        this.m_textScopeName.setLayoutData(gridData);

        //Button to set scope
         Button btnsetscope = new Button(mainDialogShell, SWT.PUSH);
         btnsetscope.setText("Set Scope");
         gridData = new GridData();
         gridData.horizontalSpan = 1;
         gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
         btnsetscope.setLayoutData(gridData);

        //Label for List of Parts to Compare
        new Label(mainDialogShell, SWT.NONE).setText("List of Parts to Compare :"); 

        //Text filed for List of Parts to Compare
        m_listKitParts = new Text(mainDialogShell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        m_listKitParts.setLayoutData(gridData);

        final Button btnCompare = new Button(mainDialogShell, SWT.PUSH);
        btnCompare.setText("Identify"); 
        gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
        btnCompare.setLayoutData(gridData);

        final Button btnCancel = new Button(mainDialogShell, SWT.PUSH);
        btnCancel.setText("  Cancel "); 
        gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 1;
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
        btnCancel.setLayoutData(gridData);

        long start_time = System.nanoTime();


        /*
        TCComponentBOMLine[]    alSelectedSRCBOMLinetemp    = eQOTMSessionInfo.getInstance().getCurrentSourceBOMLines();
        int componentsize=alSelectedSRCBOMLinetemp.length;
        for(int i=0;i<componentsize;i++)
        {
            m_listKitParts.append(alSelectedSRCBOMLinetemp[i].toString()+"\n");
        }
            */  


        InterfaceAIFComponent selectedcomponent[]=m_sourcepanel.getSelectedComponents();
        int componentsize=selectedcomponent.length;
        for(int i=0;i<componentsize;i++)
        {
            m_listKitParts.append(selectedcomponent[i]+"\n");
        }

        long end_time = System.nanoTime();
        double difference = (end_time - start_time)/1e6;

        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:Response return to TC. Total time taken: "+(difference)/1000);

        //Set scope Button Listener
        btnsetscope.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event)
            {
                //Set Scope for Compare BOMLine operation
                SetScope();
            }
        });

        //Compare Button Listener
        btnCompare.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event)
            {
                if(m_textScopeName.getText().length()<=0)
                {
                    m_textScopeName.setFocus();
                    MessageBox.post(Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_info,Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_title, 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    btnCompare.setEnabled(false);
                    btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
                    Job serverJob = new Job(eQOTMConstants.Stausmessage) 
                    {
                        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                        {
                            eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:Started backgound thread to call MI process\n"); 
                            compareBOMLines();

                            mainDialogShell.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    mainDialogShell.close();
                                }

                            });
                            return Status.OK_STATUS;
                        }
                    };
                    serverJob.setPriority(Job.SHORT);
                    serverJob.schedule();
                }               
            }
        });
        //cancel Button Listener
        btnCancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                mainDialogShell.close();
            }
        });

        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:Exit initialize UI Components for OTM compare dialog.");
    }


private boolean setSourceBomLinesOnSessionInfo() throws TCException
    {
        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.debug("In setSourceBomLinesOnCompareDialog");
        InterfaceComparable sourcePanel     =   m_currentTcApplication.getActiveComparable();
        eQOTMSessionInfo    objOTMSession   =   eQOTMSessionInfo.getInstance();
        this.m_sourcepanel=sourcePanel;

        TCComponentBOMLine[]            arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine = null;
        ArrayList<TCComponentBOMLine>   arrlcheckedBOMLine              = new ArrayList<TCComponentBOMLine>();

        if(((BOMTreeTable)sourcePanel.getCompareTreeTable()).getBOMWindow().getTopBOMLine().getDisplayType().toString().equals(eQOTMConstants.IS_MFG_PLAN))
        {           
            if( !SetScope() )//on error return false
                return false;
            if( !setCheckedBomlines(arrlcheckedBOMLine)){//on error return false
                return false;
            }
            arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine = (TCComponentBOMLine[])arrlcheckedBOMLine.toArray(new TCComponentBOMLine[arrlcheckedBOMLine.size()]);
        }else
        {
            //EBOM Install to -EBOM Install /MBOM kit to EBOM install Comparison
            arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine = ((BOMTreeTable)sourcePanel.getCompareTreeTable()).getSelectedBOMLines();
        }

        if ( arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine == null || arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine.length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.post(Messages.eQOTM_KitSelection_info,Messages.eQOTM_KitSelection_title, 2); 
            return false;
        }

        objOTMSession.setCurrentSourceBOMLines(arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine);

        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("INFO:No. of Bomlines selected for comparison : "+arrayOfTargetTCComponentBOMLine.length);
        eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.debug("Exit setSourceBomLinesOnCompareDialog");
        return true;
    }


private boolean SetScope()
    {
        InterfaceComparable targetPanel = m_currentTcApplication.getActiveComparable();
        eQOTMSessionInfo objOTMSession = eQOTMSessionInfo.getInstance();
        objOTMSession.setTargetBOMTreeTable((BOMTreeTable)targetPanel.getCompareTreeTable());
        try
        {
            objOTMSession.addUserSessionVariable(eQOTMConstants.REVISIONRULE,((BOMTreeTable)targetPanel.getCompareTreeTable()).getBOMWindow().getRevisionRule().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("Error occurred while getting RevisionRule from TC user session. Error : "+e.getMessage(),e); 
            MessageBox.post(Messages.eQOTM_ScopeRevisionRule_info,Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_title, 2); 
            return false;
        }
        TCComponentBOMLine[] arrayOfScopeTCComponentBOMLine = ((BOMTreeTable)targetPanel.getCompareTreeTable()).getSelectedBOMLines();

        if( arrayOfScopeTCComponentBOMLine==null || arrayOfScopeTCComponentBOMLine.length<1 )
        {
            MessageBox.post(Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_info,Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_title, 2);
            return false;
        }
        TCComponentBOMLine scopebomline = arrayOfScopeTCComponentBOMLine[0];
        try              
        {

            if (scopebomline.getChildrenCount() ==0)
            {
                MessageBox.post(Messages.eQOTM_ScopeNoChild_info,Messages.eQOTM_ScopeSelection_title, 2); 
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (TCException localTCException1)
        {
            eQOTMLoggerManager.logger.error("Exception Occurred while getting child count for scope");
        }

        this.m_textScopeName.setText(scopebomline.toString());

        eQBOMLineBean currentScopeBOMLine = new eQBOMLineBean(scopebomline);
        objOTMSession.setCurrentScopeBOMLine(currentScopeBOMLine);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us the code you are using

Comment: I have updated post to include code please have a look